# Login to coldbox application when login to core project

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I have following project structure..

```
WWW
   core project files and folders
   ticketSystem (coldbox project)
```

Ticket system built on framework coldbox 3.0.0. I want user automatically get logged in to ticket system as soon as they login to our core project and also I would like to share application and session variables between this two projects.

Following steps I have tried.

1. To share session and application variables I define same application name in root project and coldbox project and seems work fine.
2. To login into ticket system call security.doLogin handler through cfhttp while login into core project also pass session.urltoken to make sure it use same application and session variables.

But still I am not satisfied with this. I am looking for some proper solution to share data/call model between coldbox and non-coldbox application.

I appreciate your feedback on this.

Thanks
Pritesh

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a session cookie to say that the user is logged in? That would work if they are on the same domain. Obviously you'll want to encrypt the user identifier in your cookie. don't just do usserid = 1 as someone could easily change the value to gain access to another user's account.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I don't want to use cookie.